# In Colossians 2:9 - Are Fully Deified souls in Christ ( πλήρωμα τῆς Θεότητος) : Sinless or Omnipotent?

Tags: authorial-intent, colossians

If we [become] Fully Deity in Christ, based on [Colossians 2:9-10] which states:

> [9] For in Christ all the **fullness of the Deity** lives in bodily form, [10] and in Christ **you have been brought to fullness**. He is the head over every power and authority.

- Are Fully-Deified souls in Christ :"sinless" or "omnipotent", ("sinless" and "omnipotent")?

**What does "Fullness of the Deity" ( πλήρωμα τῆς Θεότητος) mean [for humans] in context to [Colossians 2]?**

Comment: There is no such thing (in scripture) as a 'deified soul'. This is a contradiction in terms. 'God is (a) spirit' said Jesus. (Not a soul.) The spirits of just men are made perfect,as we read, Hebrews 12:23, but they are not 'deified', thereby. 'Now are we the sons of God', 1 John 3:2,  it is written. Not 'now are we God'.

Comment: Why are you asking about sinlessness or omnipotence? I don't understand how you would get either of those things from Col 2:9-10.

Comment: @curiousdannii - The fullness of Deity must have a limit for humans on earth born into the body of Christ. | Anyone suffering as outcast or slave would be inspired to have the power to become “sinless”, but Acts 3:6-7 reveals the fullness of Deity allows apostles to heal humans like co-Creators with power of prayer. The spectrum of [sinlessness-to-miracle worker] raised the question regarding spiritual gifts associated with “fullness of Deity”, omnipotence included.

Comment: But no one other than Jesus has the fullness of deity. We're brought to fullness - the fullness of humanity, righteousness, etc - but not the fullness of deity.

Comment: @חִידָה There is no such thing in scripture as a co-Creator, save God himself and Logos.

Comment: @Nigel J - "save God himself and Logos" - exactly. There is no such thing in [scripture] as a co-Creator. Thank God for your words & may they continue to bless others, as they have blessed my Torah studies today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NIV Colossians 2:

> 9 For in Christ all the fullness of the Deity lives in bodily form,

Deity
Θεότητος (Theotētos)
Noun - Genitive Feminine Singular
Strong's 2320: Deity, Godhead. From theos; divinity.

In other words, all the fullness of the Deity lives in bodily form in Christ. Here *Deity* applies only to Christ.

> 10a and in Christ you have been brought to fullness.

In other words, you have been brought to fullness in Christ. It does not say that you acquire Deity status. This meaning is confirmed in 10b

> He is the head over every power and authority.

Christ is the head, not us.

There cannot be two omnipotent beings in a logical universe.

Comment: "There cannot be two omnipotent beings in a logical universe." - exactly

Comment: Fully agreed!! +1.

Comment: "*There cannot be two omnipotent beings in a logical universe.*"  What if one of those beings was always in agreement with the will of the other?  He could theoretically be capable of acting otherwise, but would never want to or even think of doing so. Being able to do something isn't the same as ever actually doing it.  ¶ On a much smaller scale, I am potent enough to splatter purple paint all over the rooms in my house, but in practice I won't. I could if I wanted to, but I never will.  That doesn't in any way limit my potential power.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth  The Christian stance has always been that there is only one Being of God, who is omnipotent. The theological language developed to explain this states that this one Being subsists in three uncreated, co-equal persons (or, personalities). But those who say that the second person was created by the first must know that the Creator is superior to that which he creates. A creature can never be omnipotent, as is the one Being of God, but if the second person is of that same, one Being, and uncreated, God's revealed logic in scripture clarifies this.

Comment: @Anne, that is the stance of the Roman Church and those Protestant denominations that believe in the Trinity doctrine. It isn't correct to claim this belief for all Christians. There are many Christian denominations that consider the Trinity to be non-biblical and don't accept it.  Some for instance believe God is a family, currently with two members, but soon to have many more.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth Because the Q asked about Christ having "the fullness of deity", that is why I made my comment to your comment. I won't debate the trinity doctrine but would say that mainstream Christianity has always warned against groups that say Christ was created (i.e. had a starting point in time). There is one omnipotent Being, who is complex, not simple. And although God adopts created 'children' into his heavenly family, that does not make them omnipotent, but if all the fullness of deity dwells in an uncreated Christ, he shares the divine Being.

Comment: @Anne, those that "*believe God is a family, currently with two members, but soon to have many more*" also believe that the being that was incarnated as Jesus has always existed. For instance "*We believe in one Lord, Jesus Christ of Nazareth, who is the Word and who has eternally existed.*" is in [Fundamental Beliefs of the United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/fundamental-beliefs-of-the-united-church-of-god-0), a non-Trinitarian denomination.

Answer (score 1):

**1 THESS 5:23** *Now may the God of peace Himself sanctify you completely; and may your whole spirit, soul, and body be preserved blameless at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ.*

There is debate in theological circles over the makeup of ‘man’. Some say tripartite body, soul, spirit, some are dualistic, that is, body and soul are ‘one’.

It’s true that the soul and spirit are difficult to separate, in fact there is only one ‘thing’ that can separate them ..

**HEB 4:12** *For the word of God is living and powerful, and sharper than any two-edged sword, piercing even to the division of soul and spirit,*

But, that ‘one’ *thing* is *the* ‘thing’ that matters. (The word). It’s in this understanding (of the makeup of man) that the understanding for you answer lies. If you **don’t** ‘see’ the distinction between soul and spirit, you will need to re-interpret much of Paul’s teachings..... including Colossians from which you are quoting...

It’s the numerous times Paul says that if you are a believer, then you are ‘in him’ or ‘in Christ’.

**COL 2:10** *and you are complete in Him*

The ‘key’ to this is ...

**2 COR 5:17** *Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation; old things have passed away; behold, all things have become new.*

What is ‘new’? What ‘part’ of you is a ‘new creation’? Body? Soul? or Spirit? Or is this merely ‘figurative’? This decision is yours to take, but whatever you decide, it will influence your interpretation of all of Paul’s teachings, every one of them. Bit, as I said, there is no agreement on this among theologians.

So when you asked, what does “*Fullness of the Deity*” mean in Colossians 2, the answers you get, and the answer you’ll accept depends on your viewpoint of ‘body, soul, spirit’. I say this (fullness of deity) is fulfilled ‘spiritually’, that is, via your recreated ‘spirit’. You (that is, your ‘spirit man’) has been reborn. New.

But you’ve already accepted another view so obviously won’t agree with mine. Nevertheless I post this for others to consider.

Comment: "You (that is, your ‘spirit man’) has been reborn" : Sinless, but not Omnipotent. - correct?

Comment: ‎@חִידָה Correct. There is only one who is Omnipotent.